# Replace the link of an image in a source-code by another one

Tags: python, image, web-scraping, replace

I want to make an Instagram feed preview tool using the source code of my account webpage, but I have no idea how to remove the link of an image to replace it with my own.

For the moment I am at this point:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(link)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@class='...' and contains(@src, '...')]")
```

Comment: which link do you want to replace? Is `link` to your ig?

Comment: No, the image links in the source code like : <img class="python-logo" src="/static/img/python-logo@2x.png" alt="python™" width="290" height="82">